# how to embed pdf file in flash based application (IOS and android)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I’m creating application for android and IOS using FLASH CS5.5

I want to open pdf file when I click on the button. I try to use this code but is not working

```
package
{
            import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;
            import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
            import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
            import flash.display.NativeWindowType;
            import flash.display.NativeWindow;
            import flash.events.Event;

            import flash.display.SimpleButton;


            public class bpdf extends SimpleButton
            {

                        public function bpdf()
                        {
                                    // constructor code
                                    var htm:HTMLLoader= new HTMLLoader();
                                    htm.load(new URLRequest("test.pdf"));
                                    var init:NativeWindowInitOptions= new NativeWindowInitOptions();
                                    init.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
                                    init.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
                                    var win:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(init);
                                    win.stage.addChild(htm);
                                    win.width = stage.stageWidth;
                                    win.height = stage.stageHeight;


                                    win.activate();
                                    htm.width = win.width;
                                    htm.height = win.height;
                                    win.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onCloseEvent);
                        }

                        function onCloseEvent(e:Event)
                        {

                                    trace("window closed");

                        }
            }
}
```

after publishing with “PLYER: AIR FOR ANDROID” then I got these error message in output

```
[SWF] link2.swf - 2907 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
            at bpdf()[C:\Users\HP\Desktop\PDF Link\Link_2\bpdf.as:30]
            at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
            at flash.display::Sprite()
            at flash.display::MovieClip()
            at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
            at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
            at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
            at runtime::AppRunner/run()
            at ADLAppEntry/run()
            at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

I also convert my file in APK and check in my android device but same problem when I click on the button, nothing happened

I make my APK file without include pdf and with include pdf

Include my pdf file using this way:: Publish setting > PLAYER: AIR FOR ANDROID – setting > Included files: test.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

If you want to open pdf use StageWebView instead of HTMLLoader class. Like this

```
protected function loadPDF(event:MouseEvent):void { 

var file:String = "Lorem_Ipsum.pdf";  

var yOffset:Number = 40;  

var stageWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 

stageWebView.stage = stage;  
stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, yOffset, 500, 500 - yOffset); 

 var pdf:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(file);  

stageWebView.loadURL(pdf.nativePath);
}
```

source : [more details](http://thatsthaway.blogspot.in/2012/07/display-and-remove-documents-in-air.html)

Also look at [stack overflow display-local-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979303/how-to-display-local-pdf-in-flex-mobile-project)